# Correct way to write mathematical expressions between text?

Tags: math-mode

I'm new to Latex so I'm pretty sure I have some severe misconceptions here.

I want the following output:

> Blablabla **x<sub>i</sub> ∈ X, i = 1..N** blablablabla, **1 <= I(x<sub>i</sub>) <= L**

I was trying with:

```
Blablablabla $x_i \in X, i = 1..N$ blablablabla, $1 \qeq I(x_i) \leq L$
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.72 ..., i = 1..N$ an image pixel, $1 \qeq
                                                   I(x_i) \leq L$ value of...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is `\qeq` a typo? Did you mean to write either `\leq` ("less than or equal") or `\geq` ("greater than or equal")?

Comment: hahahahah I'm laughing so I don't cry. It was that...

May I ask, so what I'm doing is fine? Is it how it's done?

Comment: For inline-math material, I would write `Blablablabla $x_i \in X$, $i = 1,\dots,N$, blablablabla, $1 \leq I(x_i) \leq L$.` Note that I would write `$x_i \in X$` and `$i = 1,\dots,N$` as separate formulas (and semantic units), to make it easier on TeX to find suitable line breaks, if needed. Note also the use of `\dots` to denote a (typographic) ellipsis.

Comment: To make it a bit more explicit: after "Undefined control sequence.", the thing at the end of the next line is what is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the error based on the typo, `\qeq` should be as `\geq`

As you are not providing any `MWE`, so I assume that you are using the standard template, and the tags are:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

Blablablabla $x_i \in X$, $i = 1\ldots N$ blablablabla, $1 \geq I(x_i) \leq
L$ 

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sebastiano Did and thanks...